# Issues with changing the file path on a C# scheduling program for an access database file causing an error while running the code

Tags: c#

We created an oledb connection on the program and we connected to a file path using a connection string. While opening the code on a different computer and changing that file name to suit the new location of the file, the system failed to read that due to dependencies. How can I change the dependencies of my code so that it works on different computers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with OLEDB connections is that you will need to recreate those connections (along with any drivers) on other operating systems where this application will be installed. As you discovered, the path alone will not work.

If you read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms?view=vs-2019), it shows the two recommended ways for access databases, both of which are OLEDB. You can try the ".NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB" option if you know .NET Framework will be installed on the other machines.

My suggestion is to change your database from access to something more portable (like plain text). Better yet, if the data can be centralized and is less than 10GB, SQL Server Express is great. You will need to have a dedicated SQL Server and then your application would use the network to read/write data. Note that if data is unique per instance, then you could program your application to auto generate a database for each instance.